# Ошибка Codeception & phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, codeception

При выполнении кода

```
$I->seeElement('h1');
```

на странице тега h1 нет, но при этом вместо fail тест падает с данным WebDriverException

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException]
  JSON decoding of remote response failed.
  Error code: 4
  The response: 'Invalid Command Method - Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Content-Length":"0","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:4444"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method"
  :"GET","url":"/log/types","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"types","directory":"/log/","path":"/log/types","relative":"/log/types","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":""
  ,"protocol":"","source":"/log/types","queryKey":{},"chunks":["log","types"]}...}'
```

в чём может быть проблема ? 
может кто уже сталкивался ?